# Rewrite that works in OSX, not working on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have a rewrite rule that works as expected on OSX (MAMP stack) but falls over on Ubuntu. The rewrite rule is as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /api
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

And the goal is to have a URL like http://server.com/api/foobar pass foobar as a variable to the index.php script. The version of Apache is somewhat different:

- OSX uses Apache/2.2.23
- Ubuntu uses Apache/2.6.14

I know that this imposes some mild syntax changes in the httpd.conf but here's what I have in Ubuntu:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
Alias /api "/home/ubuntu/repos/api"
<Directory "/home/ubuntu/repos/api">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I type in http://server.com/api/index.php/resources into the browser I get a proper response but when I try to use the redirect and type http://server.com/api/resources it just responds with a `403:Forbidden` (and yet the server error_log has no error entry).

I have also noticed that directly accessing the `.htaccess` file with http://server.com/api/.htaccess does trigger an error in the error_log:

> [authz_core:error] [pid 10351:tid 139991464257280] [client x.y.z.w:60300] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/repos/api/.htaccess
>
> **UPDATE**: this last error is now explained ... there is directive which blocks users from viewing he .htaccess file ... this is appropriate. I did turn it off briefly to see if it helped but it did not.

I checked file persmission on the file system and everything seems fine there. Must be an apache configuration problem but I'm pulling my hair trying to figure it out.

----- UPDATE ------

Directory permissions:
[image: directory]

file permissions:
[image: file]

Comment: The permissions of both the directory and the .htaccess file is readable by the apache process?

Comment: I sanity tested it anyway. all other files -- with precisely the same file permissions -- in that directory load fine.

Comment: Maybe you're just missing `Order allow,deny` on your `<Directory>` config?

Comment: Isn't that one of the things that's changed with the 2.4+ servers? I thought `Require all granted` would replace that.

Comment: I have confirmed that in v2.4 onward the `Order allow,deny` directive has been replaced by `Require all granted`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) states that the best answer is inevitably the simplest one. Ahhh where was this wisdom yesterday when I was banging my head against the wall. Anyway I've sort my problem and I'll post it here as a simple checklist item to look for if you're having a problem like I was...

For me the Apache server on Ubuntu was past the 2.4 threshold which does change some directive syntax. For anyone going from pre-2.4 to post-2.4 just make sure you change references to `Order all,deny` to `Required all granted`. This is a good step but superfluous to the problem I was having.

#### Add to your Checklist

Now the real problem ... if rewrites aren't working and no errors are being produced check your `httpd.conf` file (or whatever your primary Apache conf file is) and validate that the LoadModule for rewrites is uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

So silly but it did cost me hours. Hopefully it doesn't do the same for you.